# SVG tags don't seem sometimes while working with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, svg, fs

I had a problem with SVG tags not displaying sometimes. I refresh the page, it doesn't seem; I refresh two more times, it seems; I refresh again and it doesn't seem again. I had a little research and I've got that I need to add defer attribute to the script tag. (So, I think it was a problem that originated from the script's being executed before the page fully loaded.)

Now I add the NodeJs to the project and I've started to get this problem again. I've tried to send the HTML file by both app.get() method (express) and fs module, both don't work. How can I fix this problem?

My NodeJs code:

```
var http = require('http')
var express = require("express")
var app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html")
})

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port,() => {
    console.log(`The server is initialized on port ${port}.`)
})
```

The part of the code I use SVG (I use them as a border)

```
<button data-title="Add">
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect pathLength="305"></rect>
       </svg>
</button>
```

The CSS part (CSSs are in another file)

```
button {
            padding: 24px 0;
            font-size: 1em;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
            color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
            border:none;
            position: relative;
            outline: none;
            background: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.4s;

            &::after {
                content: attr(data-title);
                position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;
                width: 100%; height: 100%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center; align-items: center;
                transition: 0.4s;
            }

            &:hover::after {
                text-shadow: 0 0 4px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.4);
            }

            &:hover svg rect {
                fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            }

            svg, svg rect {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%; height: 100%;
                top:0;left: 0;
                fill: transparent;
                overflow: initial;
            }

            svg rect {
                stroke: #fff;
                stroke-width: 1;
                stroke-dasharray: 2 4;
                stroke-linecap: butt;
                stroke-opacity: 0.8;
                rx: 25;
                transition: 0.2s;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What content type do you serve? `text/html` or `application/svg+xml`?

Comment: If you mean what I wrote in writeHead method as the value of Content-Type, it's text/html @HeikoTheißen

Comment: Your rx needs units since you're defining it via a style. Otherwise it all looks fine.

Comment: I've added it now but nothing changed @RobertLongson

Comment: Presumably because you're only testing in Chrome.

Comment: I've tested it on Chrome, Edge and Mozilla. The problem occurs on the other browsers more seldom but it occurs. @RobertLongson

Comment: Oh, sorry. You're right. It seemed differently on Mozilla. I checked it. It's fixed now. But the main problem remains its existence. Do you have any idea about it? @RobertLongson

Comment: Yes,  use the browsers debugger and examine the network transmissions amongst other things.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the MDN SVG Tutorial for more information on using the `<rect/>` element; it's such a wonderful resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Shapes

Below is a snippet of HTML using the `<rect/>` svg element:

**File: index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe the problem you are seeing is that you have not specified the height and width of the rectangle so nothing is rendered. I am also unfamiliar with the pathLength attribute, but you may not need it.

Please let me know if this helps a bit ^^

Comment: I've specified the height and width in the CSS file.

Comment: I've seen cases where SVG doesn't render when HTML is embedded into the SVG element. Is this potentially the case? For example, if you added `<div>TEST</div>` to the above snippet, the SVG rect would no longer show.

Comment: But there isn't any HTML in SVG tags?

Comment: I didn't see that part of the answer. The parhLength attribute let me specify a total length for the border and thus I can make the measures I specified in stroke-dashArray repeat itself a specific number of times, not remain uncompleted.

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength